# Nexus 7: app is not opening

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, nexus-7

Users comment on google play that app is not opening on `nexus 7`. I am waiting for my nexus to test that issue. Right now I do not have that device.

My app is `OpenGL ES 2.0` game.

Some ppl comment on google play that app is not openning. But I do not get exception error in `Crashes and ANRs` in Google Play.

What could be a reason for that?

I have a lot of native code. Do native code exceptions are reported somehow?

Could it be a `ConfigChooser.chooseConfig` bug? Is that recommended `ConfigChooser.chooseConfig` for Nexus or most apps?

Comment: Without any logcat or code, I don't think anyone can help you. Perhaps the reason there is nothing in `Crashes & ANRs` because no user has uploaded the bug report (given that it is optional for the user to upload it). However, I do have a Nexus 7 myself, and if you post the URL to the game on Google Play, I can post a bug report for you. (Provided it is free/quite cheap I'm afraid)

Comment: The game is free https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.roolez.tinshot  Please do. Thank You!

Comment: I can confirm that the game crashes the moment you open it on the Nexus 7, however I know why you have nothing in `Crashes & ANR`... no Force Close dialogue box opens at all, you get a black screen, then the game immediately quits. I do however have the stacktrace from logcat available, the error is in some C/C++ code you have via the NDK. I have uploaded the entire log from when you open the app onto pastebin for you. http://pastebin.com/dq0kRxnn (It will expire after 1 month)

Comment: Thank You. Seems like it fails to open file to save score. Thank You very much! Please post it as answer so I can mark it as responded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm that the game crashes the moment you open it on the Nexus 7, however I know why you have nothing in `Crashes & ANR`... no Force Close dialogue box opens at all, you get a black screen, then the game immediately quits.

I do however have the stacktrace from logcat available, the error is in some C/C++ code you have via the NDK. I have uploaded the entire log from when you open the app onto pastebin for you.

Logcat: http://pastebin.com/dq0kRxnn (the link will expire after 1 month)

Comment: Could you check updated version `1.2.15` if it is fixed now? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.roolez.tinshot  I see update already.

Comment: Yep, the game now runs perfectly on the Nexus 7! :)